# Mathematica INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: DataTypes|h|254

Tags: front-end, notebooks, warning-messages

My Wolfram Mathematica recently got upgraded (I have no administrative privileges on my computer) to version 11. My noteboks and packages were all created in Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 and most of them work fine when opened by Mathematica 11.

However, when opening this notebook, this message appears:

> INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: DataType|h|254
>
> Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

Mathematica says the notebook is open, however there is a blank window, this error message "vibrates" in the message window and Mathematica stops responding.

I reported the problem, but besides helping improve the Wolfram System, I would like to have someone help me open the file and continue my work. I did send an inquiry to their technical support but while waiting for their answer maybe you have any ideas which don't include me having administrative privileges.

So far, I tried the following

- opening Mathematica while holding Ctrl+Shift (didn't work because it required me to sign in with Admin credentials)
- moving the file to another folder
- renaming the file

Any suggestions on what may be causing this error would be greatly appreciated, as well as ideas to solve it and successfully open the file.

Cheers,
Maja

Comment: You did not give any information about the notebook you're referring to.

Comment: @happyfish should I upload the notebook? should I describe the notebook?

Comment: Please upload the notebook somewhere and include a link to it in your post. Additionally, tell us the *exact* version of Mathematica you have (`$Version`) and your operating system.  Finally, it may be a good idea to email this notebook to [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/contact), so they can reproduce the problem and fix it within Mathematica.  On this site we are just users like you so we cannot do that. What we may be able to do is change the notebook to try to avoid triggering the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I couldn't provide more information than this. In the meantime, a colleague of mine, running the same system and the same version of Mathematica, on the same type of machine (sic!) managed to open the file. It said that the file containted potentially unsafe dynamic content. He saved is as a .m file, which I successfully opened and saved as a .nb file which now works.

Beats me. Thanks for your help anyway. The issue was reported to Wolfram support, I'm looking forward to their answer.